# HTTP GET "www.foo.com/content" and "www.foo.com/content/" are different?

Tags: http, web, get

I am using Firefox.

I was reading at this webpage:
https://gitbookio.gitbooks.io/javascript/content/

I accidentally typed, omitting only '/' at the end: https://gitbookio.gitbooks.io/javascript/content 
...and it shows the contents without the format.

I heard what HTTP GET reqeust `...centent/` and `...centent` are different. What I know is that requsting `...centent/`will return the list of contents of that directory or show default of that directory, and requesting `...content` will return the content of that file (`content`). Am I right? And why and how the above two links return differently? (This case it looks like the website's bug though)

Answer (score 2):

On the server side, there are no rules what the server should output with or without a trailing slash. HTTP doesn't have a concept of directories. Everything is just a resource.

But there is a difference in how the paths are interpreted on the browser side.

In this case, what happens is that without the trailing slash, the *browser* thinks that it's requesting a resource in /javascript named "content".

When it then looks up the CSS style sheet that tells the browser how to style the content, it'll look for that file in /javascript because the page used a relative link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="gitbook/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="gitbook/plugins/gitbook-plugin-exercises/exercises.css">
```

To the browser, when not using the trailing slash, the first URL translates to

```
https://gitbookio.gitbooks.io/javascript/gitbook/style.css
```

*With* the trailing slash, it translates to

```
https://gitbookio.gitbooks.io/javascript/content/gitbook/style.css
```

It's bad practice, or a kind of bug, depending on your viewpoint.